# Laravel Queue - jobs processed method

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to implement a simple multiple queue system on laravel, the feature is that users can upload csv files and later the server will process and store line by line.

Since I can't use redis, i'm using the database, and I use a different queue for every file  but for monitoring purposes I'd like that everytime a job is processed, the progress count is write on a table that holds all the imports and queues.

On the documents i've found that i can declare a failed method inside my Job class to handle fails, but what about the processed event?

Elsewhere i've found that I should use the AppServiceProviders Queue::after event, but trying to find the queue name inside the payload array data is quite painful..

Is there a better way? Maybe with processed handler inside Job's class?

Comment: Job events sounds like what you are after.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#job-events

Comment: Thanks, that's helped out